# Laravel search return data repeatedly

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function for my search and it returns results over and over

### Controller

```
function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('searchinput');
    if($q != ''){
        $links = Link::where('status', '1')
           ->where('name','LIKE', "%{$q}%")
           ->orWhere('body','LIKE',"%{$q}%")
           ->paginate(6);
        if ($request->ajax()) {
          $view = (String) view('front.links.more',compact('links'));
          return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
        }
        return view('front.search.index', compact('links', 'q'))->withQuery($q);
    }else{
        Session::flash('warning', 'You need to fill search field.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

### form

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{{route('searchin')}}">
  @csrf
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="searchinput">
</form>
```

### Route

```
Route::any('search', 'Front\SearchController@search')->name('searchin');
```

### JavaScript

```
<script defer>
        $(function(){
            var page = 1;
            loadMoreData(page);
            function loadMoreData(page){
                var isotopShowmoreJs = $('.LOADBTN'),ttAddItem = $('.tt_job_listing');

                if (isotopShowmoreJs.length && ttAddItem.length) {
                    isotopShowmoreJs.on('click', function(e) {
                        page++;
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '?page=' + page,
                            type: "get",
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                $('.ajax-load').show();
                                $('.spinner-border').show();
                            }
                        }).done(function(data){
                            if(data.html == ""){
                                $('.LOADBTN').hide();
                                $('.spinner-border').hide();
                                $('.tt_item_all_js').css('display', "block");
                            }
                            var $item = $(data.html);
                            ttAddItem.append($item);
                            adjustOffset();
                        }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert('server not responding...');
                            $('.spinner-border').hide();
                            $('.LOADBTN').hide();
                        });

                        function adjustOffset(){
                            var offsetLastItem = ttAddItem.children().last().children().offset().top - 80;
                            var $body = $('body');
                            var $html = $('html');
                            $($body, $html).animate({scrollTop: offsetLastItem}, 500);
                            $('.spinner-border').hide();
                        };
                        return false;
                    });
                };
            }
        });
    </script>
```

## screenshot

[image: onne]

## Video

https://streamable.com/qwh34

Any idea?

## update to `Aditya Thakur` comment

network

[image: two]

console `console.log(page++);`

[image: three]

console `console.log(page);`

[image: four]

## Update 2

`dd($request->all());`

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "eNio8rDaCL2du4I7KAzt5UU3ukrvHHnco3x2orUp",
  "searchinput" => "test"
]
```

`dd($request->ajax());` returns `true`

`dd($request->input('page'));` returns `null`

## Update 3

`Dan's response`

removing if condition in my controller removed second ajax request and fixed some parts.

`Sandeep Sudhakaran` response,

here is my latest result after removing if condition. PS: I marked duplicated data.

[image: five]

## Update 4

load button

```
@if(count($results)>0)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-5 mb-5 text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary LOADBTN">
                                <div class="spinner-border" style="display: none;" role="status">
                                  <span class="sr-only">{{__('links.loading')}}</span>
                                </div>
                                {{__('links.loadmore')}}
                            </a>
                            <div class="tt_item_all_js" style="display:none;">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-3" disabled>{{__('links.nomore')}}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endif
```

Comment: Of course: start running the debugger in your IDE :) Afterwards, try to guess why data is not paginated if you do not evaluate the pagination information after all

Comment: @mafortis are you open to 'workaround solutions'?

Comment: Your network shows that only every second request has a page parameter. For what's the second request without the page parameter?

Comment: @AdityaThakur meaning?

Comment: @Dan yes because second parameter is `ajax request` (which loads new data as `page=2`, `page=3` etc.) first parameter is page 1 which return first 6 results based on controller `pagination(6)`

Comment: @mafortis paginate method can take additional parameters like page number

Comment: @AdityaThakur I do have page numbers in my ajax, first page is introduced as 1 `var page = 1;` and it goes higher `page++;` in ajax url `url: '?page=' + page,`

Comment: I'm not speaking about the parameter, I'm speaking about the request. In your network tab, it seems like you're sending two requests, one to `search?page=x` and one to `search?_token=bla&searchinput=test`. The second one might be the one you've debugged in your post, because the first one doesn't contain any of the debugged parameters.

Comment: @mafortis i am just saying if you can pass the page number as data, you can get its using `$request->get('page')` then pass it to paginate method.`paginate(int $perPage = null, array $columns = ['*'], string $pageName = 'page', int|null $page = null) `

Comment: @Dan that's true it sends 2 request first one return `302` and second one `200` which is data repeatedly.

Comment: @AdityaThakur I'll try that now

Comment: @mafortis more info: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Comment: You mean `search?page=x` returns a 302 and `search?_token=bla&searchinput=test` returns a 200 with the repeated data?

Comment: @Dan yes.......

Comment: @dan https://ibb.co/YRK1RCd

Comment: you `page` parameter is passing correct. please let me know, whether the response of those three request is what you expected or it returns same result set? this will help us to find out whether the problem is with view or controller. please let me know.

Comment: You know why `search?page=x` is returning 302? Because you're checking at the beginning of the method if the `q` parameter's set and if not (as it is the case for this request) it returns an error.

Comment: @dan so if i remove that if condition will fix? :)

Comment: and do one think ans paste the screenshot. please add on label on you tiles and print the id. I think you are search for 'test' and may be you table has duplicates.

Comment: Could be. Otherwise, you're using the wrong response to fill new data.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran see update

Comment: @dan see update

Comment: is it a get method or post method?

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran `any()` see top of my question i shared route

Comment: I saw. I found no issues. and in your network screen shot it shows search is calling twice. can you please change the route more specific ? please just have a try.

Comment: you mean I change it to get or post?

Comment: yes, I thinks it is GET method

Comment: and also show you 'LOAD MORE' button's html.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran `get` method return same results as `any`, post method return my ajax error `alert('server not responding...');`

Comment: Seems like you're initially adding posts by PHP and not only by JS. Because of that, you'll need to set the initial value of the page parameter for the AJAX request to `2` otherwise you'll get the same data the first time you load new cards.

Comment: @Dan you mean i make this? `var page = 2;`

Comment: Yes, because the paginator starts at 1 and not 0.

Comment: @Dan then it starts to sends request from page 3! because first page we set as page 2!  `search?page=3` instead of `search?page=2`

Comment: @Dan https://ibb.co/YQ5s6dM.

Comment: I retract my comment. You start at `1` and incrementing it at the beginning of the function, before the AJAX request. So it was fine like this.

Comment: @mafortis, \DB::enableQueryLog();
 $links = Link::where('status', '1')
           ->where('name','LIKE', "%{$q}%")
           ->orWhere('body','LIKE',"%{$q}%")
           ->paginate(6);
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());

please do this and update the query of all three requests(page=1,page=2 and pae = 3)

Comment: @Dan it is at the beginning https://ibb.co/tHDb8FF

Comment: That's what I just wrote.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran result : https://ibb.co/dk1czCx

Comment: @mafortis for page 2 also please

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran here you go https://ibb.co/1Z6fK63

Comment: add the URL of second image

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran as you made `dd` i added page manually so here it is `http://domain.test/en/search?_token=eNio8rDaCL2du4I7KAzt5UU3ukrvHHnco3x2orUp&searchinput=test?page=2`

Comment: Look at the query. this is what I said in my previous comments. your ocunt(*) query returns empty. so the paginate was not working for rest of your requests. please show the response of your page=2 request. and we are near to your solution I think

Comment: $.ajax({
                            url: '',
                            data:{'page':page}
                            type: "get",
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                $('.ajax-load').show();
                                $('.spinner-border').show();
                            }
                        })


try this and let me know

Comment: $.ajax({
                            url: '&page='+page,
                            type: "get",
                            beforeSend: function(){
                                $('.ajax-load').show();
                                $('.spinner-border').show();
                            }
                        })

try this also.

Comment: first one you share is working

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran wow :) working and it only returns 8 results without duplicate (Perfect). thank you so much

Comment: Cool buddy. I have added the answer. please mark it as accepted and do up vote.. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ajax call like below.

```
$.ajax({ 
url: '', 
data:{'page':page}
type: "get", 
beforeSend: function(){ 
    $('.ajax-load').show(); 
    $('.spinner-border').show(); 
})
```

Comment: I need to add that removing `if($q != ''){` from controller helped to remove second ajax request (showed in my network screenshot) `suggested by DAN in comments`